# Why do the two buttons move together?

Tags: css

I hava made two buttons by CSS imitating the work from https://codepen.io/xflotus/pen/deXBzR. But they will move together when clicking one of them. I have checked the code carefully, but can not find the clue. The pen of the code is at: https://codepen.io/xflotus/pen/gzWyrg. I think the :active is not the problem:

```html
.button:active {
  margin: 2px 0px 20px 10px;
}
```

But, I have no idea how to find the bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing margins is not the best way to make a movement of a button in active state because the entire container moves down. For the movement of a single button try this code instead and remove the old code with margins:

```
.button:active{transform:translateY(10px)}
```

Now only one button will move instead of both. You can also aply -webkit-transform property if you need support in older browsers, but it's not required for new ones.

More about this topic: [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)

EDIT:

FULL CODE SNIPPET:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 68px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.button .bar {
  width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50px;
}

.button .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 11px;
}

.button .arrow .top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 3px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 9px;
  background: #000;
}

.button .arrow .bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: -2px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
.button:active{transform:translateY(10px)}


/* ---------- CSS3 ------------*/

.button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  transition: background-position .2s ease, margin .1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-position .2s ease, margin .1s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-position .2s ease, margin .1s ease;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.button:hover {
  background-position: 0 10px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #00aeef;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00aeef, #00587a);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #00aeef, #00587a);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #23aaff;
  border-top: 1px solid #23ccff;
}

.blue .bar {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #23ccff;
}

.green {
  background-color: #0f9;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0f9, #060);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #0f9, #060);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #9f0;
  border-top: 1px solid #23ccff;
}

.green .bar {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #9f0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a href="#" class="button blue">
    <div class="arrow">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    Download
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="button green">
    <div class="arrow">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    Download
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried your code before posting it? It still moves both buttons, but now the clicked one goes far.

Comment: I've edited your answer so it fit OP question, and I've added that margin need to be removed.

Comment: I made an edit and included a code snippet. Try it yourself. Only one button moves when you click.

Comment: Good job, modified my answer referring to yours

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's really a good job. Additionally, I wonder why the code from https://codepen.io/xflotus/pen/deXBzR can work. I compare them and can not find an obvious difference about the problem.

Comment: If I see correctly in this snippet there is a div container with position relative. Buttons have position absolute. If you add margin for active state it will look like a movement.

Answer (score 0):

[Jakub Muda answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138625/why-do-the-two-buttons-move-together/50138768#50138768) is better than mine in term of code, but to answer your exact question, that's because you add a margin to the clicked button, it pushes the container down, so both button move.

I modified your source https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RyVOyV and now they don't move together. The problem is that to get it, I had to make them position absolute.

```
.blue {
  position:absolute;
  top:15px;
}

.green {
  position:absolute;
  top:15px;
  left:180px;
}
```

You can manipulate them more to get them positioned relative and independent, but that out of the scope of this question.

Hope it helps ;)